# WCF operation is not running after client disconnects

Tags: c#, wcf, basichttpbinding

As far as I know BasicHttpBinding  doesn't support ReliableSession feature. So, this means that when request is received by server (wcf host) then it will be executed wether the client is disconnected afterwards or not. I hope I'm right on this?

The problem is:
I have a WCF service with BasicHttpBinding. We tested this service by calling it 10 times with different threads on the client side. And these requests are all made at the same time (almost). Right after the callings of the thread we're terminating the program by killing the process. As a result 6 out of 10 requests are executed but the 4 of the requests aren't executed. We've checked network traffic with wireshark and saw that 10 of the requests are received by the wcf service host. However, we know that 4 of them didn't executed.

(Timeout values are not configured on binding: that means they're all setted to their defaults. Also the wcf service is hosted on iis).

What's the problem here? Where can I check? What can we do to achieve 10 execution out of 10 even if the client disconnects?

Comment: Have you added the following attribute to your service?


[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode= ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

The concurrency mode must be set for handling concurrent requests.

Comment: You can be right @RavirajPalvankar: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode?view=netframework-4.7.1
On the contrary, when I debug the case it's working fine. Suppose that I'm debugging both client and server. And client sends 10 requests and when the first request started to execute on server I hit to a brakpoint and stay there until I terminate the client app. Right after the termination I let server to continue processing and it's working fine. So it's working when I'm debugging but it's not working when I'm not debugging.

Comment: Please set the concurrency mode to multiple, do not debug the code, but have a counter or something to count the number of calls made from the client and at the server, count the calls that were executed, this way you will know whether it is actually happening or not.

Comment: Now I see why there is no difference @RavirajPalvankar: I'm not expecting to run my service concurrently. I'm only expecting to run my service reliably. I mean, it doesn't matter if host can execute 10 of them at once or one by one. I only want to make sure that if host recieves 10 request then 10 executions are going to happen ( it doesn't matter to execute concurrently or sequentially).

Answer (score 0):

> What can we do to achieve 10 execution out of 10 even if the client disconnects?

You can make it the default behavior. Use `[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]` to create a one-way contract where the client does not wait for a reply, but simply disconnects after sending the message.

Comment: what about OperationContracts that are returnin some value?

Comment: If your clients disconnect, I guess they don't need a return value.

Comment: Well @nvoigt; The service's operation is designed to return some value. And, as a client, I need to make sure that my many async calls to the sevice's operation are executed. And, as a client, I'm not interested with return values: I don't care if it returns or not. But the service's operation is provided that way: it's definately returning some value, no other way. But as a client, I may ignore it: I don't have to store the return value in a variable nor keep the client application alive after the service received all of the requests.

Comment: @rebulanyum If you don't wait for a reply, how do you think the client gets to know the service even *received* the request?

Comment: The client can shutdown the OS too while waiting for the response.

Comment: @rebulanyum Sure. All kinds of things can happen. But the client cannot expect the server to do something if it does not wait for the reply. Because the reply *is the only way to know the server received the request in the first place*. There is no way for the client to know that the server received the request and is working on it and it's save to disconnect now. The client only knows two states: "request sent" and "reply received". There is no state "server received my message and is working on it".

Comment: Ok. As a client, I only care to be sure that I've sent the request (as I told it before) and don't want to care if server replied to me or not: as a client I need a "fire & forget" actually. And as a server, why the hell I'm supposed to declare my operation as IsOneWay=true just because some funky clients don't care about the return values and only cares about the job that I'm doing :). And why the hell I have to declare an overload with void return value of my operation just because of that. I hope you could understand my concern on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you really need the service to be completed even if the client disconnects i think there is a database transaction that you need to be done.

In case the WCF is connecting to a database, this would be normal especially if you are using the same database user and password, if this is the case try to connect once for all WCF instances.

either way you have to make sure that your WCF provide concurrent access. click [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) for more information of concurrent WCF access.

Comment: sorry @bilal-sultan-al-tamimi but that's not the case: not interested with db transactions on service side.